# merge 2 projects using maven and eclipse with OSGi

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, osgi, apache-karaf

I have done 2 projects who are working well . One from[1] http://www.liquid-reality.de/display/liquid/2011/12/22/Karaf+Tutorial+Part+4+-+CXF+Services+in+OSGi
and one from  [2] http://baptiste-wicht.com/posts/2010/07/osgi-hello-world-services.html

The first project [1] is a form who run with soap and restfull
The second project [2] is a hello world who run with OSGi service

I would like to merge theses 2 projects. 
This mean one can use the other , how to do it ? 
For example  when  I add someone in the form , the project [1] send a message (with OSGi service) to the project [2].

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

So if I understood correctly you want to have one bundle that offers an OSGi service and a second project that offers a servlet and calls the osgi service with the data from the form.

This is done in my first tutorial:
http://www.liquid-reality.de/x/DIBZ

and here is the corresponding code:
https://github.com/cschneider/Karaf-Tutorial/tree/master/tasklist

Comment: Thank you but your link is a big project , i want to do some thing easy and to walk step by step.

I need to know how to make OSGi service, this turorial show how to me how to make osgi service, http://www.javaworld.com/article/2077837/java-se/hello--osgi--part-1--bundles-for-beginners.html?page=2

firstly, Where is the manifest file in [1] http://www.liquid-reality.de/display/liquid/2011/12/22/Karaf+Tutorial+Part+4+-+CXF+Services+in+OSGi ?

Comment: the answer of my question " Where is the manifest file in [1] " is here : http://www.mkyong.com/maven/how-to-create-a-manifest-file-with-maven/

Comment: yes. The Manifest is generated automatically which is quit convenient. Btw. my project looks big but is quite small in lines of code. I just had to split it into separate sub projects to show the design.